# How to use App.config File?

Tags: c#

I have created a simple windows application and added a `App.config` file

I have also added Settings file which also adds keys into `App.config` file.

```
<appSettings> 
    <add key="myKey" value="1"/>    
</appSettings>
<applicationSettings>
    <MyApp.AppSettings>
        <setting name="RunAutomated" serializeAs="String">
            <value>False</value>
        </setting>
    </MyApp.AppSettings>
</applicationSettings>
```

Inside my code have the following :

```
If(AppSettings.Default.RunAutomated) {
    Console.WriteLine("Running auto!!!");
}
else { 
    Console.WriteLine("Running manual!!!");
}
```

Simple is that.

When I **build the project** and run it through visual studio everything is as expected that output changes when I change RunAutomated key and re run the application.

But this is not true when I go under **/bin/Debug** folder and run the **MyApp.exe**

It seems to cache app.config and it ignores the changes to app.config file.

How should I do this simple task to keep reading the App.config file every time it is run? any changes I am making app.config should affect the application?

Comment: I'm sure there's a duplicate somewhere, but your `app.config` is copied to `AppName.exe.config` every build. So when rebuilding, you're back to defaults.

Comment: I'd only use `app.config` where absolutely necessary (e.g. assembly redirection). For custom configuration I'd use a separate file together with some serializer.

Comment: Can you explain better how do you change that value? Do you change it in code? Do you change it in app.config before running the debug session? Directly on the exe.config in the debug folder?

Comment: Changing AppName.exe.config seems to be working instead of changing app.config file. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have altered the property in code, or using a UI in your app, you should save the altered properties by calling [`Save`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.settingsbase.save%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the `SettingsBase` instance:

```
AppSettings.Default.Save();
```

Note that after every build the settings file is overwritten, so try to copy the executable to another folder and run it multiple times.

Alternatively you can create your own settings file, which I find easier and more reliable. You can take a look at the [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class and the `JsonConvert` class in [Newtonsoft Json](http://james.newtonking.com/json).